# How do i include the csrf_token to dropzone Post request (Django)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, dropzone.js

Allright this is resolved. Just editing in case anyone runs into the same problem.

Add the Code posted in Comment marked as answer in the same javascript file.
When defining

```
var myDropzone =  new Dropzone(...
  ...//More stuff here
  headers:{
    'X-CSRFToken' : csrftoken
  }
```

And thats it.

So im getting a 403 Forbidden when submitting the POST request through dropzone.js to django.Django displayed the message saying that I didnt include the CSRF token, but I don't know how to actually include it if im not using a form in the HTML.

## document_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'  %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block title %}Add files{% endblock %}
{% block files %}
<div class="container-fluid" id="container-dropzone">
<div id="actions" class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <span class="btn btn-success file-input-button">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      <span>Add files...</span>
    </span>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
      <span>Start upload</span>
    </button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
      <span>Cancel upload</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-5">
  <!-- file processing state -->
    <span class="fileupload-process">
      <div id="total-progress" class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table table-striped files" id="previews">
  <div id="template" class="file-row">
    <div>
      <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
      <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
      <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0"
                 aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%" 
                    data-dz-uploadprogress>
        </div>           
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary start">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
        <span>Start</span>
      </button>
      <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-warning cancel">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
        <span>Cancel</span>
      </button>
      <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        <span>Delete</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- /table-striped  -->
</div> <!-- /container-fluid  -->
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block dz-add %}
  <script src="{% static 'js/dropzone-bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

## dropzone-bootstrap.js

```
$(function() {
  var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
  previewNode.id = "";
  var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
  previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

  var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.querySelector("#container-dropzone") , {
    url: "/dashby/files/add/", //url to make the request to.
    thumbnailWidth: 80,
    thumbnailHeight: 80,
    parallelUploads: 20,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    autoQueue: false,
    previewsContainer: "#previews",
    clickable: ".file-input-button",
    headers: { // Tried to apply the token this way but no success.
      'X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file){
    file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").onclick = function(){
      myDropzone.enqueueFile(file);
      };
  });

  myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress){
    document.querySelector("#total-progress .progress-bar").style.width = progress + "%";
  });

  myDropzone.on("sending", function(file){
    // Show total progress on start and disable START button.
    document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "1";
    file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  });

  // Hide progress bar when complete.
  myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(progress){
    document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "0";
  });

  // Setup buttons for every file.
  document.querySelector("#actions .start").onclick = function(){
    myDropzone.enqueueFiles(myDropzone.getFilesWithStatus(Dropzone.ADDED));
  };
  document.querySelector("#actions .cancel").onclick = function(){
    myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
  };
});
```

In my **base.html** im adding all the required files (dropzone, jquery, bootstrap and my custom javascript file)

For the django form handling:

## views.py

```
class DocumentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Document
    fields = ['file']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        data = {'status': 'success'}
        response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype =
        response_mimetype(self.request))
        return response
```

## My "Document" model

```
class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'files/',
                                validators=[validate_file_type])
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    extension = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank = True, null = True)

    def clean(self):
        self.file.seek(0)
        self.extension = self.file.name.split('/')[-1].split('.')[-1]
        if self.extension == 'xlsx' or self.extension == 'xls':
            self.thumbnail = 'xlsx.png'
        elif self.extension == 'pptx' or self.extension == 'ppt':
            self.thumbnail = 'pptx.png'
        elif self.extension == 'docx' or self.extension == 'doc':
            self.thumbnail = 'docx.png'

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #delete file from /media/files
        self.file.delete(save = False)
        #call parent delete method.
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

    #Redirect to file list page.
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dashby-files:files')

    def __str__(self):
        #cut the 'files/'
        return self.file.name.split('/')[-1]

    class Meta():
        #order by upload_date descending
        #for bootstrap grid system. (start left side)
        ordering = ['-uploaded_at']
```

I created a Json response to handle the dropzone.

## response.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

MIMEANY = '*/*'
MIMEJSON = 'application/json'
MIMETEXT = 'text/plain'

# Integrating Dropzone.js with Django.
def response_mimetype(request):
    can_json = MIMEJSON in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']
    can_json |= MIMEANY in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']
    return MIMEJSON if can_json else MIMETEXT

# Custom HttpResponse
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, obj='', json_opts=None, mimetype=MIMEJSON,
                *args, **kwargs):
        json_opts = json_opts if isinstance(json_opts, dict) else {}
        content = json.dumps(obj, **json_opts)
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, mimetype,
                                          *args, **kwargs)
```

I've been stuck with this problem for a day now, so decided to ask for help here as I havn't been able to find one.

Thanks to anyone that takes the time to read and for any help/tips that I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django’s docs have a [reference for this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/csrf/#ajax):

> While [a special parameter] can be used for AJAX POST requests, it has some inconveniences: you have to remember to pass the CSRF token in as POST data with every POST request. For this reason, there is an alternative method: on each `XMLHttpRequest`, set a custom `X-CSRFToken` header to the value of the CSRF token. This is often easier, because many JavaScript frameworks provide hooks that allow headers to be set on every request.
>   […]
>
> Acquiring the token is straightforward:
>
> ```
> // using jQuery
> function getCookie(name) {
>     var cookieValue = null;
>     if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
>         var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
>         for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
>             var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
>             // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
>             if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
>                 cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return cookieValue;
> }
> var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
> ```
>
> […]
>   Finally, you’ll have to actually set the header on your AJAX request, while protecting the CSRF token from being sent to other domains using [settings.crossDomain](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) in jQuery 1.5.1 and newer:
>
> ```
> function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
>     // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
>     return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
> }
> $.ajaxSetup({
>     beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
>         if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
>             xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```

If you run these two code blocks before you start to make requests, it should Just Work™.

In summary, just use this code block:

```
// from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/ via http://stackoverflow.com/a/39776325/5244995.
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I put all this code in my javascript file before the `$(function(){});` logic for dropzone but im getting the error still. Do i need to call it somewhere specifically?

Comment: Allright figured it out. Inside dropzone config I used the cookie as a value for the header. thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I have just figured this out, all you need to do is add this to your dropzone config:

```
headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
```

good luck!

Comment: This is the one. Simple and it just works™.

Answer (score 2):

just place `{% csrf_token %}` anywhere  in your Html file . it's automatically add

```
 <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="**************" />
```

Before sending data to the server just add extra field `csrf_token` which value is `$("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();`

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax) recommend getting the CSRF token from the cookie, not the DOM. Try that.

Comment: Could you help me implement that? i read the docs but im not sure where to do it.

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old thread, I thought I'd share the solution that worked for me.

```
var myDropzone = $("#file-upload").dropzone({
        url: "/dashboard/api/v1/upload/",
        // addRemoveLinks : true,
        maxFilesize: 5,
        dictResponseError: 'Error uploading file!',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': window.CSRF_TOKEN},
        success: (file, response) => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(file.xhr.response));
        }
    });
```